# What exactly does "Ethernet-capable HDMI cable" mean?

Tags: cable

What exactly does "Ethernet-capable HDMI cable" mean?

Does this mean I can stream content wirelessly to my projector?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No it does not mean you can do anything wirelessly - it is a cable - and it isn't likely to help you stream anything to it either, unless you have a requirement for HDMI devices to share a network connection.

Version 1.4 of the HDMI standard allows for 100Mb ethernet to be transmitted along the cable between to HDMI 1.4 capable devices.

Check out the [HDMI wikipedia](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/HDMI) page for some basic info

Comment: I've noted that the crop of current-gen TVs have an increasing amount of multimedia functionality. Taking this one step into the future, if (in theory) you had a display, NAS (or other storage medium) and an amp / switcher all supporting HDMI ethernet you could likely forego the requirement to have a separate network cable to connect them all together. Single cable streaming! I like the logical step of removing another cable, the final thing we we need is Power over Ethernet over HDMI (PoEoH... 'poweoh'? Sounds like Schwarzenegger trying to pronounce 'power' ;-) - THEN we're cooking with gas.

Comment: Why would an Ethernet-enabled HDMI cable be cheaper than a regular HDMI cable, all else equal? For example at this link: http://www.monoprice.com/products/subdepartment.asp?c_id=102&cp_id=10240; 35ft 24AWG CL2 Standard HDMI® Cable With Ethernet - Black is $28.78 while 35ft 24AWG CL2 Standard HDMI® Cable - Black is $29.29. I just need a 35ft HDMI cable, is there any reason to not get the Ethernet-enabled one, since it is cheaper? Thanks.